# How to uninstall Tex-Live, installed on Linux with the Perl script?

Tags: texlive, installing, linux, debian

I installed TeX-Live on Debian 11 using [instruction with a perl script](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). However, turns out that I don't need it for now, and since it took around 10 GB of my disk, I decided to uninstall it. However I found no instruction on it. At most, I cleaned 300 Mb by doing simple

```
apt purge texlive-*
```

(`autopurge` doesn't clean much either)

So, how do I clean the remained gigabytes?

Thanks.

Comment: If you used the perl script, you installed vanilla texlive and not the texlive packaged with linux distributions.  `apt ...` will only deal with the texlive packaged with linux. To uninstall vanilla texlive, follow the "Pre-install: download, cleanup" instructions on the site you linked to. You basically just have to remove the folder `/usr/local/texlive/` (or whatever installation location you chose)

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much. Removed!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: (sudo) `tlmgr remove --all` is what I would have suggested; but probably too late now